# fgets function behaves oddly

Tags: c, sqlite, fgets

So I am writing a program that takes 4 inputs from the user: a username, a password, a phone number and an address; The program then uses `sqlite3` database to insert this data into an existing table.

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sqlite3.h>


void newregister()
{
char new_user[200];
char new_pass[200];
char new_phone[200];
char new_address[200];
printf("Enter your desired username: \n");
fgets(new_user, 200, stdin);
printf("Enter your desired password: \n");
fgets(new_pass, 200, stdin);
printf("Enter your phone number: \n");
fgets(new_phone, 200, stdin);
printf("Enter your address: \n");
fgets(new_address, 200, stdin);

printf("new user = %s \n", new_user);
printf("new pass = %s \n", new_pass);
printf("new phone = %s \n", new_phone);
printf("new address = %s \n", new_address);
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
int rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
if(rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Problem opening Database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
char *sql = "INSERT INTO Users VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, NULL, 0);";
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, 0);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) 
{
        fprintf(stderr, "Problem executing INSERT: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
else
{
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, new_user, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, new_pass, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, new_phone, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 4, new_address, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
}

int step = sqlite3_step(stmt);
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
sqlite3_close(db);
}
int main()
{
newregister();

return 0;
}
```

The problem that I'm facing is that it doesnt insert the lines properly even though the `printf` seems to work fine.

Here is how the table looks like:

```
User        Password    Phone       Address               Cart        Total_Price
----------  ----------  ----------  --------------------  ----------  -----------
user1       pass1       1234567890  Str user nr 1                       0          
user2       pass2       1234586970  Str user nr 2                       0          
user3       pass3       2138321321  Str user nr 3                       0          
user4       pass4       8908702131  Str user nr 4                       0          
user5       pass5       9082313123  Str user nr 5                       0          
user6       pass6       9083213123  Str user nr 6                       0          
user7       pass7       0932382383  Str user nr 7                       0          
user8       pass8       3829832323  Str user nr 8                       0          
user11
 pass11
 1234567890  strada broscautilor
          0
```

If I used `scanf` then the entries would go normally up to the point where I have a space because `scanf` stops when it reaches whitespace. However I tried using `scanf` with different formatting that allows whitespace and I have the same problem as well as the fact that scanf with the same formatting 4 times stops taking input after the third time.
Would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fgets` function reads a line of text and writes it **including the newline** into the given character array.

You'll need to strip out the newline before continuing with processing.

```
fgets(new_user, 200, stdin);
char *nl = strrchr(new_user, '\n');
if (nl) *nl = 0;
```

Comment: seems to work except the last 2 fields which are not inputted by user also share the problem and the 0 from the new registered line appears below the table